# Is there a way to use the material handling Library to assign a randomly generated list of items to a worker to collect from storage shelves

Tags: anylogic

Essential, I aim to model the picker process in a warehouse. In my scenario a worker is given a randomly generated list of items to complete an order. The worker goes to the storage and complete the order. In my model each agent/worker only collects a single item per run and I'd like to know how to set each worker to randomly collect multiple items(say ten) in one run

I added the storage shelves and added the retrieval block and assigned worker agents to it. I did not know how to set up the picker scenario

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `RackSystem` as shelves, so you can use the function `myRackSystem.randomAgent()` to select a random pallet from the RackSystem.

If when you generate your pallets you put them into a population, So you can use the function `randomWhere( pallets, p -> p.weight > 1000 )` to select a random agent from a population and satisfying the specified condition.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your suggestion it works

Comment: By the way, is there a way to have a defined(non-random) list of items assigned to agents consistently throughout the model runtime?  I'm trying to account for some items occurring in more frequent than others in order requests

Comment: Sure, see different functions [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/subset.html).